# Is it possible share token between apps using Smart Lock without web service?

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

If user logged in one my app that save token with Smart Lock is it possible to get this token in second my app without using complex scheme with web service?

Comment: What do you mean "complex scheme with web service"?

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites I need associate my apps with my web-site which will store Digital Assets Link file. Am I right? But I haven't such site so this scheme looks complex. It would be convenient to simply get the user's token and id stored in Smart Lock for each my app without associate them with web-site. Cases for invalid tokens will be processed on the app side (with possibly prompt user to re-login and next storing new valid token in Smart Lock)

Comment: Are the different apps running on the same device? Why not just use the Account Manager? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Comment: Yes, I was considering the AccountManager option. It seems less convenient, since it assumes a separate application-authenticator and after re-installation of authentificator app user must re-enter his credentials. Also Account Manager can't share token between user's devices (Smart Lock provides this wonderful functionality).

Comment: How are you saving tokens via Smart Lock?

Comment: As an option, as password in com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials object

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against putting tokens in the password fields, as they will autofill and be treated as passwords in UI and account settings...

Comment: So is it possible do it in another way?